# get rgb images from sentinel-2 using gdal

Tags: sentinel-2, gdal-merge, rgb, sentinel-snap

i have some troubles to get RGB true colors image from sentinel satellite bands

[image]

wich produce this
[image]

to me it looks not natural at all

also i have tried gdal to do the merge with :

```
gdal_merge -o merged.tif -of GTIFF B04.jp2 B03.jp2 B02.jp2
```

but gave me an unusable file, at least in microDEM .

so i am wondering what's wrong here ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the `-separate` option in order to *place each input file into a separate band* and (optionally) the `-co PHOTOMETRIC=RGB` creation option to force the photometric interpretation (to avoid e.g. the `ColorInterp=undefined` and set the right color interpretation for each band):

```
gdal_merge -separate -co PHOTOMETRIC=RGB -o merged.tif B04.jp2 B03.jp2 B02.jp2
```

Note: `-of GTIFF` is not necessary because GeoTIFF is the default output format.

Another approach consists into scaling the input bands before *gdal_merging* (but it's not strictly necessary in clients, where the bands are stretched):

```
for %%i in (4,3,2) do gdal_translate -scale B0%%i.jp2 B0%%i.tif
gdal_merge -separate -co PHOTOMETRIC=RGB -o merged.tif B04.tif B03.tif B02.tif
```

Finally the output needs some fine tuning operations, like the cut of histogram (e.g. a cumulative count cut) and the calibration of brightness, contrast and saturation, in order to be an acceptable RGB representation to use in GIS/RS clients or elsewhere. The following is a quick and dirty Sentinel-2 RGB sample created with `gdal_merge` and then visualized in QGIS:

[image]

Comment: unfortunally , this gave me a black image inside microdem http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/922035bands2.jpg

Comment: here the gdalinfo of the merged file http://www.mediafire.com/file/2799z1ys1x9n0wi/out.txt

Comment: pleas note that Band 2 and 3 have ColorInter=undefined (don't know what this mean ...)

Comment: @user2475096 I've added further details above, but the answer is substantially the same. I think that the black image issue is MicroDEM specific. Try also in other GIS client, e.g. QGIS, calibrating the visualization parameters after loading the RGB image and let you know. us if it works fine.

Comment: it worked this time :) but like you said it need a lot of tweaking to get a "natural" true color image . anyway thanks a lot, really appreciate !